# Getting UUID from Mach-o binary under Java?

Tags: java, ios, macos, mach-o

Are there any existing tools or libraries to grab the UUID(s) from the Mach-o binary load command header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After attempting to us [`objdump`](http://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/) from my Groovy process.

```
"objdump -P load ${filename}".execute()
```

I couldn't get this to work under our Ubuntu servers, even after I compiled `binutils` with arm support.

I ended up hacking together a really quick and dirty library to read Mach-o binaries. I'm going to avoid posting it here because it was done so quickly, but a coworker of mine took some time and wrote up what looks like a much more robust solution, https://github.com/dzog/machismo

Answer (score 1):

otool -l? or did I misunderstand your question

Comment: I meant native libraries that a Java program could use. I think I may end up calling out to shell command since my searching has been fruitless.